# how does runtime instance deal with provided scope dependency?

Tags: maven, deployment, scope, dependencies

i am interested in understanding maven scopes during build life cycle.
i understood that working with a dependency, like this one :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

the javax.servlet-api jar will not be included in the final executable jar,
because the server is supposed to already possess the dependency.
ok, but how does it work ?
where is physically the util jar ? (javax.servlet-api.jar)

last question :
when we build a jar, how can we be sure the dependency can be tagged as provided scope,
so that the server already has it, for the run ?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually up to you to make that sure. Maven does not know about it.

So if you know that your server provides certain dependencies (e.g. because you read the server manual), then you can mark them as `provided`.